# Snappy Daemon hanging on boot?

Tags: snap, fsck

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I suddenly had a problem booting into Ubuntu.

A start job is running for Hold unt...finishes up (32min 30s / no limit)

I'm not 100% sure it is snappy but I don't know what else it could be. The messages are displayed as 
Started Snappy daemon 
Stopped Snappy daemon
over and over again.

Pressing cntl + shift + f1, f2 doesn't seem to do anything.

I've searched around but haven't found anything definitive as to how to work on it. I'd love any help.

Edit: I dual boot with windows 10 - fast startup is disabled. I've had this setup for more than six months without issues. I also uninstalled Ext2 File Manager from Windows because it was causing superblock errors. After I used fsck the errors would be fixed and I could boot into Ubuntu without issue.

Here is a photo of the screen from about 2 minutes.
[image: Screen photo of boot screen]

Comment: Try hitting control-c to abort the startup process, and edit your question with the output of `sudo systemctl status apt-daily.service` and `sudo systemctl status nmbd.service` and `sudo systmctl status winbind.service` and `sudo systemctl status snap.tor.tor.service`. Do you know how to fsck your Ubuntu file system? See my partial answer for the procedure.

Comment: I've been unable to abort the startup process. I'll add some more details to my post.

Comment: Are you able to boot into Recovery Mode from the GRUB menu?

Comment: I had been able to get into recovery mode but read-only errors kept appearing. I ended up running fsck over and over again and it finally worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets check your filesystem first...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

The user had a Windows driver that allowed ext2 access to the Linux/Ubuntu file system. Guaranteed to corrupt them. Uninstalled it. fsck now runs clean.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done fsck, it had some errors, they were repaired and I am still having a problem.

Comment: I did it again a few more times and it worked! I must have run fsck a million times

Comment: I don't know how to marked Solved.

Comment: @ZebGriffin please read my Update #1, then to mark it as solved, click the little grey checkmark icon just to the left of my answer. You can also click on the grey up arrow icon to give extra points. Thanks!